# posgresql: Selecting specific column in an existing table and sort it according to absolute values in descending order?

Tags: javascript, sql, sorting, absolute, temporary

I have the following table:

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  Date    |     A    |    B    |     C    |     P    |     D    |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|2019-01-10| -111,000 | 666,000 |   78,000 |       45 |  120,000 |
|2019-01-09|  555,000 |  55,000 |  100,000 |       55 |  700,000 |
|2019-01-08|   48,000 |  30,000 |   40,000 |       65 |  450,000 |
|2019-01-07|  600,000 |-450,000 | -800,000 |       90 |  980,000 |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

May I know how to create a temporary table from the existing table above to become the table as below:

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|  Date    |Components|  Values | Comp_no  |     P    |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
|2019-01-10|     A    |-111,000 |     1    |       45 |
|2019-01-10|     B    | 666,000 |     2    |       45 |
|2019-01-10|     C    |  78,000 |     3    |       45 |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Then sort it according to absolute values as below:

1. Give numbers to the largest value as '1', 2nd largest as '2' and so on.

The sorted_comp_no represents the order whereby the components is sorted where '1' is 'B', '2' is A and '3' is C.

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+
|  Date    |Components|  Values | comp_no  |     P    | sort_sequence|
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+
|2019-01-10|     A    |-111,000 |     1    |       45 |       2      |
|2019-01-10|     B    | 666,000 |     2    |       45 |       1      |
|2019-01-10|     C    |  78,000 |     3    |       45 |       3      |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

2. Use the comp_no and sort.

The components are now sorted according to their values.

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+
|  Date    |Components|  Values | comp_no  |     P    |sorted_comp_no|
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+
|2019-01-10|     B    | 666,000 |     2    |       45 |       2      |
|2019-01-10|     A    |-111,000 |     1    |       45 |       1      |
|2019-01-10|     C    |  78,000 |     3    |       45 |       3      |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

I've already created the temporary table template but still stuck in taking the name of specific column only (A,B and C) to be put into a column of its own category ignoring column D . Column P is brought into the temporary table but remain as is. There is also a dependency to the date column as there are multiple data of different date.

But the end goal is to be able to "**sort specific column according to its absolute value at a specific date dynamically**".

Comment: have you tried ABS() function?

Comment: Your question only makes sense if there exists a column which can provide for the first ordering.  I see no such column.  Please clarify your question.